# How to center text in an inline-block span on lte Firefox 2?

Tags: firefox, center, css

I have 3 spans inside a div.

1. `text-align: center` doesn't comply
2. `text-align: -moz-center` neither
3. **I have to use spans**
4. **no floats**
5. `display: -moz-inline-block` is working but the 2nd and 3rd spans clear left…

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Well if an inline-block element doesn't have a width specified, then it will collapse down to the width of the text contained within it, which means a text-align property would be useless for that particular element. (And why on Earth are you using FireFox 2?)

Comment: He said "lte firefox 2" so i guess he needs it for Less Then Equal firefox 2, which can mean he might be using firefox 1? O.o

Comment: the spans have a width set / I am not - my clients are.

Comment: get them to upgrade? There's no reason not to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

replace `<span>text</span>` by `<p><span>text</span></p>`

CSS

```
p {display:-moz-inline-stack;text-align:center}
span {display:block}
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

```
div{
    width:80%;
    display:table;
}
span{
    width:33%;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #F00;
}
```

Note that both the div AND span width need to be changed to adjust widths. The span should be 100/(no of spans)% and the div whatever width you want.

Comment: the width is not respected (shrink to the text width) anymore and ill have to use css hack (cause lte ie7 doesn't support table-cell)

Comment: That's weird.. it works for me on ff2 with width:300px; As far as using table-cell goes, the impression I got was that you only cared about supporting ff2?

Comment: Check out the edits. Its a little hacky, but the best I can come up with.

Comment: ok thx wer almost there but now the margin (in %) on the spans isn't working anymore

Answer (score 0):

Just put some left and right padding on those spans?

So if you have something like this:

```
<div>
    <span>some text</span>
    <span>also some text</span>
    <span>again here comes some text</span>
</div>
```

Just use it like this in your css:

```
span{
padding:0 10px;
}
```

Result will be something like this:

http://i48.tinypic.com/5knczm.jpg

Note, i added 1px border, so you would see that text is "centered"...

Comment: I can't do it cause im using a flexible layout (width in %) > i tried using % or auto and it's not working.

Comment: Then dont use inline element like span. Do it with unorder list.

Comment: i tried it but it's not working in my case cause each li with have a different text's length (using % to center with padding and display:inline) and im getting the same result with lis for #5 and #6 (not centered or clears left) / i want all 3 spans on the same line